# Diferencia entre while y for en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hay alguna diferencia entre usar la instrucción for y while? (En los casos en que se permitan ambas formas, claro está).

Por ejemplo, los siguientes codigos:

```python
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

```python
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Hay alguna diferencia en rendimiento o de algun otro estilo en usar una u otra instruccion? Gracias.

Comment: has hecho las pruebas para determinar su rendimiento?

Comment: No sabría como hacerlo. Podrías darme una idea de como buscarlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una pregunta que no es nada fácil de responder. Depende de qué versión del intérprete python uses (CPython, Pypy, pyodide, ...) y de cómo hagan las optimizaciones.

Sin entrar en cómo trabaja el intérprete, podemos analizar qué hace cada bucle:

- La versión *while* hace dos operaciones: `i < 10` y `i += 1`. Con el incremento se crearán nuevos *objetos* (números enteros).
- La versión *for range* llama a la función `range()` para obtener un iterador que recorre el bucle para dar valores a `i` hasta quedar exhausto. Sin entrar en lo que haga `range()`, el bucle en sí no crea ningún objeto.

Si tenemos N iteraciones, el intérprete python tendrá que hacer `2*N` operaciones y crear `N` objetos con el bucle *while*, mientras que con el bucle `for range` sólo tiene que llamar a una función e invocar el iterador, todo optimizado en lenguaje de bajo nivel.

La pregunta sería: *¿qué es más eficiente, las operaciones y creación de objetos que hace el `while`, o la llamada a `range()` y recorrer el iterador que hace el `for`?*

La función `range()` y el iterador están optimizados (programado en C/C++ en el caso de CPython). Para un caso general, debería ser mucho más eficiente que usar el `while`. Pero hay optimizadores que saben optimizar el bucle `while`, siempre que no dependa de código externo. No se puede decir cuál de los dos bucles tendrá mejor rendimiento sin ver casos concretos.

Aún hay más. Cuando digo que `i += 1` _"crea objetos", no es del todo cierto. El intérprete de python crea al inicio todos los objetos que piensa que va a necesitar. Entre otros, crea todos los números enteros del `-1` al `256`, por lo que en el bucle `while` del ejemplo, cuyo entero mayor será `10`, ¡no crea ningúno de los números que usa!.

Dejando de lado el rendimiento, sí que hay algo que es importante considerar. Con el bucle `while` no se puede impedir que la variable de control sea modificada y que el bucle acabe antes de tiempo o que se produzca un error con la expresión de control. Estos problemas están más limitados con el bucle `for`, lo que es razón suficiente para recomendar su uso.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el módulo time, e hice la siguiente prueba:

```py
import time

inicial_for = time.time()

for i in range(1000000):
    i += 1

print(time.time() - inicial_for, "segundos con FOR")

inicial_while = time.time()
n = 0
while n < 1000000:
    n += 1

print(time.time() - inicial_while, "segundos con WHILE")
```

Tomo el tiempo antes de la ejecución de cada uno de los bucles, tomo el tiempo al finalizar, y realizo la resta, para saber el tiempo de ejecución.

Devuelve los siguientes valores:

```
1000000 iteraciones
0.12027621269226074 segundos con FOR
0.12313008308410645 segundos con WHILE

10000000 iteraciones
1.1102118492126465 segundos con FOR
1.192373514175415 segundos con WHILE

100000000 iteraciones
10.883198022842407 segundos con FOR
11.439775705337524 segundos con WHILE

1000000000 iteraciones
107.99017834663391 segundos con FOR
114.22435331344604 segundos con WHILE
```

En la primera ejecución, las diferencias son mínimas, y se intercalan entre el for y el while. A mayor número de iteraciones, se nota más la diferencia de que el while es más lento en ejecución.

Espero que a alguien le sirva, gracias!

Comment: eso se debe a que el `while` debe realizar una comprobación en cada iteración, en cambio el `for` sigue hasta que ocurra un `StopIteration`

Comment: Esto no puede ser un problema de la implementacion de python @Christian??? en tal caso, la pregunta deberia ser si hay alguna diferencia en tiempo...

Comment: @gbianchi pues no sé, pensé que en un while siempre se ejecutará una comprobación de la condición, en cambio en el `for` nop. Y sí, la pregunta debería de ser sobre el tiempo y no sobre los ciclos en sí.

Comment: el for tambien tiene una condicion de corte.. en todos los ciclos.. esto es un problema de implementacion de un lenguaje interpretado... @Christian

Answer (score 0):

El rendimiento no es el punto: un `for` se ocupa para recorrer secuencias y un `while` para ejecutar mientras se cumpla una condición.

El concepto central del `for` es ir sacando elementos uno por uno hasta agotarlos todos:

```
for elemento in lista:
    ----
```

En el `while` la cantidad de elementos no es conocida de antemano; tienes que procesar hasta que se cumpla una condición que te diga parar. Ejemplo: procesar una entrada de teclado hasta que el usuario ingrese "exit"

```
opcion = ''
while opcion != "exit":
    ----
```